# Easy Image is not uploading into director by ckeditor in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

i want to upload content and image from backend by using ckeditor where content upload successfully and show on frontend but image not show on front page kindly help.

Comment: show some code... so we can help easily

Comment: <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="TextBox3"  BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
                </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>

just get content from Ckditor using ID and insert into database table

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not be using [ASP.NET control](http://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Advanced). It is considered obsolete and should only be used by legacy applications. Proper approach is to use latest CKEditor 4.x JavaScript with Code Behind attached to textarea on which the editor is created.

Once you have the correct editor used, you have 3 options for enabling images upload:

1. You can use commercial File Manager like CKFinder: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3/, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/
2. You can use commercial Easy Image service: https://ckeditor.com/docs/cs/latest/guides/easy-image/quick-start.html, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_easyimage_integration.html
3. You can create your own file manager/custom uploader. How it can be done has been described in File Manager section (please read all 6 links): https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_browse_upload.html

Hope it helps.